# What kind of chart is this and how to create it in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Does anyone [know what kind of graph this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BfGM.jpg)? It plots all values on a horizontal line from low to high and let's you highlight the value of the subject you are interested in (in this case it's a football player).

Does anyone also know if it's possible to make such a graph with Python and what command to use in something like matplotlib?

Comment: In matplotlib you would create this with a bunch of `scatter` plots (one in grey and one in red) and a `plot` for each median.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, scatterplots with the values of your variable on the x-axis and the y-values of your variable all the same number. And then make multiple scatters. Thank a lot!